# Is it possible to uncheck a user's slicer selection based on the input from another?

Tags: powerbi

This is a question about unchecking user inputs from a slicer that has a hierarchical relationship with another. As an example, a user selects ‘fruit’ from a ‘level 1’ slicer and ‘Apples’ from the ‘level 2’ slicer. They then change their mind and select ‘cars’ from the ‘level 1’, however Power BI holds onto ‘apples’ from the original selection, leading to a nonsensical slicer combination.
Is it possible to reset/uncheck the ‘level 2’ slicer whenever the user makes changes to the level 1 slicer? I have already investigated using bookmarks, but a slicer isn’t able to trigger a bookmark. Please note that the two slicers need to be separate items.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Hi Hackaholic, I've tried a few things:
- Using bookmarks to reset the level 2 slicer
- Editing the direction of the slicer interactions
- Using DAX to validate the user selection (then filtering the slicer with the DAX measure)